# Can single queue subscribed to many consumer in Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, publish-subscribe

I am trying to create Pub/Sub microservice application using Amazon SQS. With a single publisher and multiple subscribers(consumers). Messages are consumed by the subscriber based on the message attributes. Also, a single message can be consumed by multiple subscribers.

Is my approach correct?

If it is show which consumer will be responsible for dequeuing message from the SQS ?

FYI - I am using Typescript / Express for this not using serverless stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages sent to an **Amazon SQS queue** wait until a consumer requests a message. When the message is retrieved, it is made 'invisible' on the queue so no other consumer will receive it. When a consumer has finished processing the message, it deletes the message from the queue.

Therefore, if you want multiple consumers to receive the same message, then Amazon SQS is **not** the correct service to use.

Since you want a publish/subscribe model, **you should be using Amazon Simple Notification Service** (Amazon SNS). Messages are published to a 'Topic' and multiple subscribers can receive messages sent to that topic. Subscribers can use [Amazon SNS subscription filter policies - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html) to limit which messages they receive.

Note that messages sent to an Amazon SNS topic are *immediately* sent to subscribers. If you do not wish to receive a message in real-time, it is possible to **subscribe an Amazon SQS queue to an Amazon SNS topic**. This way, the messages will be queued for later retrieval. The queue would work independently to other subscribers on the topic.